# Compare ARE of mean and median

Tags: mean, median, efficiency

I have followed some lectures on the internet on asymptotic relative efficiency. When I had calculated the relative efficiency $ARE(median, mean)$ than my result was $ARE(median, mean)=\frac{2}{\pi}\approx 0.637$. Thus my conclusion was that the mean is about 64 % more efficient than the median (under normal distribution). Then from curiosity, I begin to calculate $ARE(mean, median)=\frac{\pi}{2}\approx 1.57$ I know that the mean has to be more efficient under the normal distribution. Then my conclusion was that the mean has to be about 57 % more efficient. I do not see a problem with my calculations. My common sense told me that if I compare mean to median or median to mean I have to obtain the same results. My question is why these two results are different.

Comment: $ARE(median, mean)=\frac{2}{\pi}\approx 0.637$ suggests the median is about $36.3\%$ less efficient than the mean for a large sample from a normal distribution.  Note that $\dfrac{1}{1-0.363} \approx 1+0.57$.  Think about a $20\%$ reduction: to get back where you started, you need a $25\%$ increase so these are not symmetric

Comment: Oh, I see. I had a problem with the interpretation. However, still there is a problem with the asymmetry that you have mentioned. Maybe this asymmetry is what my question is about.

Comment: So $40$ is $20\%$ less than $50$ while $50$ is $25\%$ more than $40$. This is the same but with less round numbers

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. Thank you very much that explains everything.